# Decorators that make the affected function return false?

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a Django function, `read_detail`, which returns True or False based on whether a user is allowed to read a page. The function is repeated in several different classes with differing logic, but there is one piece of logic that I think will always be the same, which is returning True if the user is a superuser. I'd like to set it up like this:

```
@is_superuser
def read_detail()
```

where `@is_superuser` will force `read_detail()` to return True if the user is a superuser, and no further evaluation will occur. Then I can avoid repeating this bit of logic across classes. Is this possible?

Comment: What's the logic to see if some user is superuser?

Comment: Please consider to give your function a more sensible name like `can_read_details()`. Now it looks like your function will read some details.

Comment: The use of decorator in your particular case is also questionable. I don't know the background very well, but these two lines of code are really simple and easy to read: `if is_superuser(): return True`. Now you want to remove these 2 super simple lines and add 1 line which gives no clue about what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

```
class is_superuser(object):

def __init__(self, fn):
    self.fn = fn
    self.is_super = False

def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_super: return True
    return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)



>>> @is_superuser
... def blah():
...   return "baz"
... 
>>> blah()
'baz'
>>> blah.is_super = True
>>> blah()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would decouple the predicate logic from the decorator, along the lines of

```
def true_if(predicate):
    return lambda fun: lambda *a, **k: predicate() or fun(*a, **k)
```

and then

```
def is_superuser():
    return ...your logic....


@true_if(is_superuser)
def read_detail():
```

Similarly, you can define `false_if`, `true_unless` etc. Looks quite useful to me.